# Pass TextBox.Value to Modal Form Label.Text OnClick

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, textbox, label

I want to capture the cursor coordinates over an image in a modal form when the image is clicked but I'm suck on the javascript. I also want the modal form to open *ONLY* when the image is clicked. The modal form currently pops up when the user clicks anywhere in the window. Bonus marks for anyone who can help me get the modal form centered in the window as well!

Any insights will be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<a onmouseover="document.body.style.cursor='crossHair'" 
    onmouseout="document.body.style.cursor='default'" 
    onmousemove="getXY(event)">
    <img id="Image" src="../Images/TestImage.jpg" alt=""/></a><br/><br/>

X = <input type="text" id="xVal" size="1" readonly="true"/> &nbsp;
Y = <input type="text" id="yVal" size="1" readonly="true"/><br/><br/>

<div id="mask"></div>
<div id="container">
<div id="submitDialog" class="window"><br />

X-coordinate:<asp:Label ID="lblX" runat="server"></asp:Label><br/>
Y-coordinate:<asp:Label ID="lblY" runat="server"></asp:Label><br/>
```

**Javascript**

```
  function getXY(e) {
        var txtX = document.getElementById("xVal");
        var txtY = document.getElementById("yVal");

        MouseX = (e).offsetX;
        MouseY = (e).offsetY;

        txtX.value = MouseX;
        txtY.value = MouseY;
    }

$(document.getElementById('#Image')).click(function() {

        launchWindow('#submitDialog');

        $(window).resize(function() {

            var box = $('#container .window');

            //Get the screen height and width
            var maskHeight = $(document).height();
            var maskWidth = $(document).width();

            //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
            $('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight });

            //Get the window height and width
            var winH = $(document).height();
            var winW = $(document).width();

            //Set the popup window to center
            box.css('top', winH / 2 - winH);
            box.css('left', winW / 2 - winW / 2);
        });
    });

    function launchWindow(id) {

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(document).width();

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(document).height();
        var winW = $(document).width();

        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen 
        //and mask position
        $('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight });
        $('#mask').css({ 'top': 0, 'left': 0});

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(500);
        $('#mask').fadeTo("fast", 0.8);

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top', winH / 2 - winH);
        $(id).css('left', winW / 2 - winW / 2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(500);

        //These are not setting the label text :(
        $('#lblX').text($('#xVal').val());
        $('#lblY').text($('#yVal').val());
    }
```

**CSS**

```
#mask 
{
   position:absolute;
   z-index:9000;
   background-color:#000;
   display:none;
}

#container .window 
{
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  height:490px;
  display:none;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  color:black;
}

#container 
{
  position: relative;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution below addresses all of the issues I was having previously. My fix to get the modal form to be "centered" was a bit of a hack but it suited my purpose well enough. Hopefully this can be useful to someone else out there!

**HTML**

```
<a id="imageAnchor" onmouseover="document.body.style.cursor='crossHair'"
    onmouseout="document.body.style.cursor='default'" onmousemove="getXY(event)">
       <img id="Image" src="../Images/TestImage.jpg" alt=""/></a><br/><br/>

X = <input type="text" id="xVal" size="2" readonly="true"/> &nbsp;
Y = <input type="text" id="yVal" size="2" readonly="true"/><br/><br/>

<div id="mask"></div>
<div id="container">
<div id="submitDialog" class="window">

X-coordinate:<asp:Label ID="lblX" runat="server"></asp:Label><br/>
Y-coordinate:<asp:Label ID="lblY" runat="server"></asp:Label><br/>

<asp:HiddenField id="xCo" runat="server"/>
<asp:HiddenField id="yCo" runat="server"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
function getXY(e) {
            var txtX = document.getElementById('xVal');
            var txtY = document.getElementById('yVal');

            //hack for firefox - it doesn't like the offsetx/y property
            if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
                MouseX = e.pageX - document.getElementById("Image").offsetLeft;
                MouseY = e.pageY - document.getElementById("Image").offsetTop;
            }
            else {
                MouseX = e.offsetX;
                MouseY = e.offsetY;
            }

            txtX.value = MouseX;
            txtY.value = MouseY;
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#imageAnchor').click(function(e) {
                    launchWindow(e);
            });
        });

        function launchWindow(click) {

            //Get the screen height and width
            var maskHeight = $(document).height();
            var maskWidth = $(document).width();

            //Get the window height and width
            var winH = $(document).height();
            var winW = $(document).width();

            //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen 
            //and mask position
            $('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight });
            $('#mask').css({ 'top': 0, 'left': 0 });

            //transition effect     
            $('#mask').fadeIn(500);
            $('#mask').fadeTo("fast", 0.8);

            var window = $(document);
            var body = $(body);
            var element = $('#submitDialog');

            //Set the popup window to center
            $('#submitDialog').css('top',50);
            $('#submitDialog').css('left', window.scrollLeft() + Math.max(0, 
                window.width() - element.width()) / 2);

            //transition effect
            $('#submitDialog').fadeIn(500);

            if (click) {

                if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
                    MouseX = (click.originalEvent).pageX - 
                        document.getElementById("Image").offsetLeft;
                    MouseY = (click.originalEvent).pageY - 
                        document.getElementById("Image").offsetTop;
                }
                else {
                    MouseX = (click.originalEvent).offsetX;
                    MouseY = (click.originalEvent).offsetY;
                }

                $('#ctl00_MainContent_lblX').text(MouseX);
                $('#ctl00_MainContent_lblY').text(MouseY);

                //store coordinates in hidden fields & clear InvalidInput textbox
                $('#ctl00_MainContent_xCo').val(MouseX);
                $('#ctl00_MainContent_yCo').val(MouseY);            
            }
            else {
                var hiddenX = $('#ctl00_MainContent_xCo');
                var hiddenY = $('#ctl00_MainContent_yCo');

                $('#ctl00_MainContent_lblX').text(hiddenX.val());
                $('#ctl00_MainContent_lblY').text(hiddenY.val());
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document.getElementById('#Image')).click(function(e) {

    // Add the event argument to the handler function to get mouse position
    // then pass that into the launch window function.

    //Put in the DIV id you want to display
    launchWindow('#submitDialog',e);

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var box = $('#container .window');

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(document).width();

        //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth + 'px', 'height': maskHeight + 'px' });

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(document).height();
        var winW = $(document).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        // You need the height of your popup to do this.

        var pHeight = $(id).height();
        var pWidth = $(id).width();

        // Check to see if the window will come off the page, because
        // you're not gonna want that.

        var top = ((winH - pHeight) > 0) ? (winH - pHeight) / 2 : 0;
        var left =  ((winW - pWidth) > 0) ? (winW - pWidth) / 2 : 0;

        // If you don't set it to 'px' you may have trouble with some browsers

        box.css('top', top + 'px');
        box.css('left', left + 'px');
    });
});
function launchWindow(id,mouse) {

    var offset = $('#Image').offset();

    // Here are the coordinates you were looking for

    var coords = {
       x: mouse.pageX - offset.left;
       y: mouse.pageY - offset.top;
    }
    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(document).width();

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(document).height();
    var winW = $(document).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen 
    //and mask position
    $('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight });
    $('#mask').css({ 'top': 0, 'left': 0});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(500);
    $('#mask').fadeTo("fast", 0.8);

    //Set the popup window to center
    // You need the height of your popup to do this.

    var pHeight = $(id).height();
    var pWidth = $(id).width();

    // Check to see if the window will come off the page, because
    // you're not gonna want that.

    var top = ((winH - pHeight) > 0) ? (winH - pHeight) / 2 : 0;
    var left =  ((winW - pWidth) > 0) ? (winW - pWidth) / 2 : 0;

    $(id).css('top', top + 'px');
    $(id).css('left', left + 'px');

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(500);

    //These are not setting the label text :(
    $('#lblX').text(coords.x);
    $('#lblY').text(coords.y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response James. Your solution looked promising but unfortunately didn't work when I tried implementing it. The labels in the modal form still pop up as blank when the image is clicked, the modal form still pops up when any part of the window is clicked as opposed to just the image and your centering calculation was even further off than my original one :(

Comment: Haha really? Sorry about that. I do know how to do this because I've done it a million times. I just wrote that code in SO so I didn't actually test it. I'll try it again today.

Comment: It's all good. I'm still working on it as well so I guess whoever posts first gets the points!